# Defining what a distributed transaction really is in .Net

Tags: .net, transactions, transactionscope

I'm wondering, If I have a method that needs to update some value in a database, but also send a SOAP message to an external system, is this a two-commit transaction? Operations must either both pass or fail. I'm looking at this from a .Net perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Distributed Transactions are only about databases queries.
The transaction scope is a way to handle the sql transaction in .NET (maybe distributed or maybe against one sql instance).

The transaction is commited when you call the `scope.Dispose()` method, if you need to do a webservice call to validate your query, you can do it (between the db call and the `scope.Dispose()` call. But I would not recommend it since your transaction is hanging in the meantime, causing locks and waiting time in your databases.